# Nextjs 14, Auth issue

Tags: next.js, cookies, next-auth, setcookie

Please help
I am new in nextjs, I unable understand i can fix my problem

I have multiple application in reactjs
In which one manage authentication & authorization and from it redirecting other application with token in URL then set the token to local storage.
Now one more application i need to create on nextjs,
So I have auth(JWT) token in URL, This token i want to set in cookie so that i can call other api with jwt token

I want to set token in cookie, token are getting from landing request in application